# Chrome-html select doesnt recognize value if keyed in

Tags: google-chrome

I have an address form with select option for list of states. If i key in (tab and focus on the state dropdown, then key in "I" ), it shows Idaho as selected, and when I submit form it shows no value selected for state. But if I click on the dropdown and select the state using click, submit works fine. This issue is only in chrome, it works fine in FF and IE.