# Select option selected via jquery not working on chrome only

Tags: jquery

I cant figure it out why it doesn't work on chrome only whereas it working on firefox and ie.

HTML CODE:

```
<select name="goyale" id="goyale">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">Fish</option>
<option value="2">Chicken</option>
<option value="3">Meat</option>
</select>
```

jQuery CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select#goyale option[value='<?php echo $row['goyale']; ?>']").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Whenever i inspect element on chrome, it displays the option as `<option value="3" selected="selected">Meat</option>` but the option doesn't appear selected on naked eye display.

Thanks.

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727694/jquery-chrome-select-change-click-not-working-works-in-ie-ff ?

Comment: Ok, after i updated jquery 1.6 to jquery 1.7, the problem is gone and the select mechanism is working fine now. Thanks for help

Comment: You probably have error in your server side code. Please post the rendered html from the page source. I have no clue what $row['goyale'] returns. Your client side code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/vh6uh/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within jQuery 1.6, once i update to jQuery 1.7, the problem gone and the select function is working as intended. Thank you and i have should have updated to latest version before posting here.

Comment: anyone know WHAT isn't working in 1.6? I ran into this issue to but we can't upgrade to 1.7 yet.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the Prop method. I tested it on Safari, Opera, Firefox, and Chrome, and it worked fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test - Option selected - jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <select>
        <option value="11">aa</option>
        <option value="22">bb</option>
        <option value="33">cc</option>
        <option value="44">dd</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('select option:last').prop('selected','selected');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find more information here:

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for any `select` element with the `id` of `goyale`. In your HTML, `goyale` is the `name` attribute of your element.

Uses this instead:

```
$(function(){
    $("select[name='goyale']").etc();
});
```

Also, use `prop()` to add the selected attribute to `option` elements:

```
$("option[value='<?php echo $row['goyale']; ?>']").prop("selected",true);
```

More about `prop()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop).

Comment: my bad, the id was there on original code and its not working

Comment: @cicakman: Check your source code--is the PHP echoing the right data?

Answer (score 1):

i Hope this will solve your problem

```
$("#goyale").val("<?php echo $row['goyale']; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

ok do this , give id="goyale" in  tag ,because may be chrome not support selector # id selector for "name" attrib, else try option[name=goyale] selector of jquery

Comment: my bad, the id was there on original code and its not working